# How can I trigger a function when switching sheets within a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

How can I trigger a function when switching sheets? The main goal is to track how people is using a spreadsheet. I found the following option that does exactly this, but it is only tracking the case where I switch between sheet, but not when other people do it:

```
var PROP_NAME = "lastSheetIdx";
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

function timedEventHandler() {
  var currentSheetIdx = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getIndex()
  var previousSheetIdx = parseInt(userProperties.getProperty(PROP_NAME));
  if (currentSheetIdx !== previousSheetIdx) {
    didSwitchSheets(previousSheetIdx, currentSheetIdx);
    userProperties.setProperty(PROP_NAME, currentSheetIdx);
  }
}

function didSwitchSheets(from, to) {
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Engagement");
  Logger.log("Switched from " + from + " to " + to);
  sheet.appendRow([new Date(), to, Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
}
```

Any advice how can I change this script, so it will track anyone (getting their email) switching between sheets?

For context, we use GSuite, so it should be ok for us to pull the email addresses being the same domain.

Comment: There is no trigger for that.  If you must do it, is it worth running a clientside dialog that polls your spreadsheet  once every few seconds?

Comment: @cooper, I planned to user a time Trigger so the script runs every minute. Is not perfect, but at list I'll get some data. The problem is that currently is only working for me ie. if another user goes between sheets, they are not tracked. Not sure what I need yo change so they are also tracked.

Comment: So the trigger will be time based, and the script will run every minute. This isn't ideal but I don't see any other way to trigger when a user is changing between sheets. Would appreciate any ideas here! @Cooper can you provide an example for the "clientside dialog that polls every few seconds'? will that be invisible to the user? otherwise I won't be able to use it

Comment: also, how can I get the name of the pervious sheet instead of the index with "lastSheetIdx"? I can't find "lastSheetIdx" in the docs, is there a "lastSheetName"?

Comment: I think I would try using an installable onEdit trigger. Build your own trigger script so every one can use it and in the onEdit track all the edits in a log which could be a spreadsheet or just a text file inset the time stamp and the sheet from e.range.getSheet() and range with e.range.getA1Notation and then you poll that spreadsheet or log file ... I would use a file.

Comment: thansk @Cooper I might be missing something, but the problem is that people accessing the spreadsheet, won't make edits. I want to find a way to log every sheet they visit. onOpen works for the first time they access the sheet, but not when they move around the different sheets. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: Ah. I forgot about that. Well then it’s not possible.

Comment: makes sense. Any context on what is ""lastSheetIdx" in my script? I'd like to get the sheet name instead of the index

Comment: It's name of a key into the PropertiesService.  It looks like it's the kind of script you might want but unfortunately it will only work on the spreadsheet that you open.  Because if you open a spreadsheet any other way other than a user opening it you don't get a user interface it simply gets opened on the server an the activesheet is always SpreadsheetApp.openById().getSheets()[0] which is the sheet on the right hand side.  So you will never get any sheet changes with that.

Comment: iFrame your spreadsheet in your website. Then you can track